# How initialize some data only if needed when there's async functions implicated

Tags: c#, async-await, singleton, lazy-initialization

My website needs to initialize some data only if the app required it and it must be done only once. The initialization must call an API to get the data.

So basicaly, i think i need to make a **lazy singleton** that will call the api when it will be accessed for the first time. But i've got a problem when i used the async method GetAsync from the HttpClient class. Something have crashed when calling the API but the exception haven't be caught by my TryCatch.

I tried to transform the `Piv GetPiv()` to a `Task<Piv> GetPiv()` but i don't know how to use it with the Lazy object.

```
public class PivHelper
{
    private static readonly Lazy<Piv> _lazyPiv = new Lazy<Piv>(GetPiv);

    public string Header()
    {
        return _lazyPiv.Value.Header;
    }

    public string Footer()
    {
        return _lazyPiv.Value.Footer;
    }

    public string Scripts()
    {
        return _lazyPiv.Value.Scripts;
    }

    public string Styles()
    {
        return _lazyPiv.Value.Styles;
    }

    private static Piv GetPiv()
    {
        try
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("http://some-web-site.com").Result;

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                return response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Piv>().Result;
            }
            else
            {
                return new Piv();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new Piv();
        }
    }
}

public class Piv
{
    public string Header { get; set; }
    public string Footer { get; set; }
    public string Styles { get; set; }
    public string Scripts { get; set; }
}

public static class MtoHelper
{
    private static readonly Lazy<PivHelper> lazyPivHelper = new Lazy<PivHelper>(() => new PivHelper());

    public static PivHelper Piv
    {
        get
        {
            return lazyPivHelper.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

My _Layout.cshtml file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Instead of using our own copy of the piv.css, we use the one
         coming from the webservices -->
    <!--<link href="~/content/piv.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">-->
    @MtoHelper.Piv.Styles()

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
</head>

<body>
    <header id="pageHeaderContainer" class="container">
        @MtoHelper.Piv.Header()
    </header>

    <section id="main" class="container">
        @RenderBody()
    </section>

    <footer id="pageFooterContainer" class="container">
        @MtoHelper.Piv.Footer()
    </footer>

    @MtoHelper.Piv.Scripts()
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Invoking `.Result` is often a bad idea.  Can you just make `GetPiv()` async?  `public static async Task<Piv> GetPiv()` ?  Then you could `await` the async operations invoked therein.

Comment: This is what i have tried to do but then, how can i use the Lazy object if the GetPiv is a Task<Piv>. This is where i'm stuck.

Comment: Fair question.  This looks helpful: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2011/01/15/asynclazyt/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `async` and `await` keywords. Using `.Result` causes issues. You could implement an `AsyncLazy` class like below, this would allow you to ensure that the invocation on the `GetPiv` occurs only once.

```
public class AsyncLazy<T> : Lazy<Task<T>>
{
    public AsyncLazy(Func<T> valueFactory) : base(() => Task.Run(valueFactory))
    {
    }

    public AsyncLazy(Func<Task<T>> taskFactory) : base(() => Task.Run(taskFactory))
    {
    }
}
```

Then you'd have to alter your code to utilize the aforementioned keywords:

```
public class PivHelper
{
    static readonly AsyncLazy<Piv> _lazyPiv = new AsyncLazy<Piv>(() => GetPivAsync());

    public Task<Piv> PivTask => _lazyPiv.Value;

    static Task<Piv> GetPivAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                var response = await client.GetAsync("http://some-web-site.com");

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    return await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Piv>();
                }
                else
                {
                    return new Piv();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new Piv();
        }
    }
}

public class Piv
{
    public string Header { get; set; }
    public string Footer { get; set; }
    public string Styles { get; set; }
    public string Scripts { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your API code you could consume the helper as such (I made some assumptions about using ASP.NET Core for its Web API):

```
public class PivController : Controller
{
    private readonly PivHelper _helper;

    public PivController (PivHelper pivHelper)
    {
        _helper = pivHelper;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> GetPiv()
    {
        var piv = await _helper.PivTask;
        // Act on the piv, or simply return it...
    }
}
```

**Update**

Based on the OPs edit, I need to update my answer.

You are incorrectly doing MVC. The entire idea is to have a separation of concerns and promote best practices in terms of following principles such as SOLID. Your view **should not** be aware of the `PivHelper` but rather the `Piv` model, and your controller **should** know about the `PivHelper` as it is the provider of the `Piv`.

As far as requiring a model as part of your layout, that is a different battle. I advise against it and suggest that you keep your layout to just the links to `.css` and script tags for your `.js` with the minimal amount of elements.

Comment: I'm using the results inside the _layour.cshtml file in a MVC5 project. In fact, the example that i've put in my description is a smaller version of the real thing. The `public string Header()` is actually a `public MvcHtmlString Header()` so i can use it directly in my views. So it cannot be a Task<Piv>

Comment: Sure it can, show me your controller action that corresponds to the view and I will update my answer with how it is done.

Comment: I have updated the description with how the layout is done. My controllers are not aware of the PivHelper. Only the layout file use it.

Comment: I think it depends of how you see the problem that i need to solve. At the beginning, we used hardcoded css, scripts, header and footer html in the project. This is header and footer that every internal web site need to use. Instead, we've put a webservice that give to each website the right header and footer to print. So this is just a replacement on how we manage to print the general stuff. For example. Instead of writing `<link href="~/Content/piv.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`, we just print `@MtoHelper.Piv.Styles`.